# Different query results between "Yii2 activequery" and "Navicat"

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I am debugging a feature. And I found two different query results of the same sql statement. The sql statement executed against the same database and table.

SQL execution by Yii2's ActiveQuery gave result #1 (8 records).
SQL execution by Navicata gave result #2 (11 records).

Here is the code:

> "count($payload["id_tag"])" is always zero

```
  $where = [];
  $where[] = "and";
  $where[] = "is_delete = 0";
  $where[] = "linked_id_question <> -1";
  $where[] = ["in", "status", [-3, -2, 1, 4]];
  $where[] = ["in", "id_kategori", $payload["id_kategori"]];

  if( count($payload["id_tag"]) > 0 )
  {
    $where[] = ["in", "ftt.id_tag", $payload["id_tag"]];
  }

  $test = ForumThread::find()
    ->join("join", "forum_thread_tag ftt", "ftt.id_thread = forum_thread.id")
    ->where($where)
    ->orderBy("time_create desc")
    ->all();
  $total_rows = count($test);
```

Here is the sql statement generated by Yii's activequery:

```
SELECT 
`forum_thread`.* 
FROM 
`forum_thread` 
join `forum_thread_tag` `ftt` ON ftt.id_thread = forum_thread.id 
WHERE 
(is_delete = 0) AND 
(linked_id_question <> -1) AND 
(`status` IN (-3, -2, 1, 4)) AND 
(`id_kategori`=46) 
ORDER BY `time_create` DESC;
```

Here is the sql statement I wrote on the Navicat:

```
select
  *
from
  forum_thread
    join forum_thread_tag ftt on ftt.id_thread = forum_thread.id
where
  is_delete = 0 and
    linked_id_question <> -1 and
    status in (-3, -2, 1, 4) and
    id_kategori in (46)
order by 
  time_create desc;
```

Both queries were executed against the same database and table. No changes on the records.

As you can see, the sql statement joins forum_thread and forum_thread_tag tables (one-to-many relationship) and it SHOULD return 11 records. But why Yii2's activequery returned 8 records (as if it process the result with DISTINCT operator).

Any idea why the Yii's ActiveQuery gave different result?